# Почему слайдер не работает ни в одном браузере?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/unslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/unslider-dots.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Company name - home page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="center-block-main">
            <div class="header-top clearfix">
                <p class="logo">BIRUANG</p>
                <div class="contact-basket">
                    <p class="header-phone"><img src="images/ico-phone.jpg" alt=""> +371 282 20 760</p>
                    <p class="header-basket"><img src="images/ico-basket.jpg" alt="">  $99.54    <a href="#">Checkout</a></p>
                </div>  
            </div>  
            <div class="header-bottom clearfix">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">WOMEN</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">KIDS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SALE</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                </nav>  
                <div class="search-block">
                    <form action="1" method="get">
                        <input type="image" src="images/search-btn.jpg" class="search-btn" alt="search">
                        <input type="search" class="search" placeholder="Search...">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </header>

    <div class="my-slider">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h2>RIGHT IS PINK.<br> LEFT IS BLUE</h2>
                <p>Inspired by Brasil’s bold colors and matching up to football’s on-pitch<br>
                playmakers, these kicks are ready to stand out.</p>
                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="slide1">
           </li>

            <li><h2>RIGHT IS PINK.<br> LEFT IS BLUE</h2>
                <p>Inspired by Brasil’s bold colors and matching up to football’s on-pitch<br>
                playmakers, these kicks are ready to stand out.</p>
                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="slide1">
            </li>

            <li><h2>RIGHT IS PINK.<br> LEFT IS BLUE</h2>
                <p>Inspired by Brasil’s bold colors and matching up to football’s on-pitch<br>
                playmakers, these kicks are ready to stand out.</p>
                <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="slide1">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/unslider-min.js"></script> 
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)  (
            $('.my-slider').unslider();
        ));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добрый вечер.
Замените "круглые" скобки на "фигурные".

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.my-slider').unslider();
    });
```

p.s. Большинство ошибок можно увидеть в консоли браузера или логах сервера. Заглядуйте туда почаще.